# Cannot write to created HTML file in Java

Tags: java, html, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Here is my code:

```
public static void create() {
        String path = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "\\JWPLfile";
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                File f = new File(path + index + ".html");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
                bw.write(fileContent);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the newly created HTML file is empty although fileContent is not.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { index++;}` Shouldn't you do something useful with the exception instead of incrementing an index you're not even using? Even just printing the exception message. That may give you a lot more insight into the problem.

Comment: Did you close the output file?  I don't see evidence in your code that you did.  Use try-with-resources to auto-close it.

Comment: I use index to specify the name of the file. What I was thinking was if I cannot create the file then there is already a file with that name so I try to increment it. What else can I do with the exception other than printing exception message? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Yes, that was it! If you write an answer I will select as the answer. Thank you @JimGarrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the file is closed. Use try-with-resources as in:

```
        File f = new File(path + index + ".html");
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f)) {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(fileContent);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            index++;
        }
```

Note that the (essentially) empty `catch` block will hide any exceptions from you.  Not a good idea.

Also, `while(true)` and `break` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim's answer says, the empty catch block is a bad idea. Instead check whether the file exists first and increment `index` until it doesn't:

```
int index = 0;
File f;
do {
  f = new File(path + index++ + ".html");
} while (f.exists())
...
```